# Cloud Formation Templates

Tags: amazon-cloudformation, templates

I have an EC2 instance running with security group, IAM, firewall and all needed software running in my production environment. Is there a way for me  to generate a template that I can use in Cloud Formation in order to roll out new instances with the same configuration.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Yes,

**CloudFormer** is the CloudFormation template generator that can get information about your existing AWS infrastructure and transform it to CloudFormation template.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html